# Cannot check the users login are in mySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm totally beginner
I'm connecting to mySQL database with python by package mysql-connector. I've created login system, added data to the database, but I can't check the users are in the database using if statement. When I pass a good username and password I get the elif statement. Does Anyone know what is wrong with the code?

```
def OldUser():
  mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Users")
  Users = mycursor.fetchall()
  oldusername = input("Username: ")
  oldpassword = input("Password: ")

  if oldusername and oldpassword == Users:
    print("Login was successfully!")
  elif oldusername and oldpassword != Users:
    print("Something was wrong, log in you again")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Users variable contains all the rows returned from the query. You'll want to iterate over each row before you check the username / pw:

```
for user in Users:
  # Assuming the column order is (username, password)
  if oldusername and oldusername == user[0]
    print("Login was successfully!")
  elif oldusername and oldpassword != user[1]:
    print("Something was wrong, log in again")
```

You can also simplify the query by filtering by username

```
def OldUser():
  oldusername = input("Username: ")
  oldpassword = input("Password: ")
  mycursor.execute("SELECT password FROM Users where username = %s", oldusername)
  if mycursor.rowcount > 0:
    # Check password
    row = mycursor.fetchone()
    if oldpassword == row[0]
      print("Login was successfully!")
    else:
      # Invalid password
      print("Something was wrong, log in again")
  else:
    # User not found
    print("Something was wrong, log in again")
```

Here's an article that may help you: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/python-mysql-query/

Comment: You may also want to look into hashing+salting your passwords: https://www.okta.com/security-blog/2019/03/what-are-salted-passwords-and-password-hashing/